# Path-dependent types and generics

Tags: scala

I am looking at an example from [Abstract Members](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/abstract-members.html). We have the following example of path-dependent types.

```
class Food

abstract class Animal {
  type SuitableFood <: Food

  def eat(food: SuitableFood): String
}

class DogFood extends Food

class Dog extends Animal {
  type SuitableFood = DogFood

  override def eat(food: DogFood): String = food.toString
}

val lassie = new Dog
lassie eat new lassie.SuitableFood
```

Say we want to work with eat in an class in the following manner

```
class D[T <: Animal] {
  def blah(t: T, p: T): String = {
    t.eat(t)
  }
}
```

I get `type mismatch; expected t.SuitableFood, actual: T`. I see that I am entering the waters of generics and path-dependent types. I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: `T` isn't of type `SuitableFood`, it is an `Animal`. Is there a typo in `t.eat(t)`?

Comment: How do I say it's of type `SuitableFood`?

Comment: I guess you can just add a type parameter to the function, like this: `def blah[F <: SuitableFood](t: T, food: F): String = t.eat(food)`.

Comment: That doesn't compile. I thought you need `T#SuitableFood` but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Well, what is the compile error?

Comment: For `def blah[F <: T#SuitableFood](t: T, food: F): String = t.eat(food)`, I get `type mismatch; expected t.SuitableFood, actual: F`

Comment: Same for what you proposed

Comment: See Alexey's answer. That should be what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I say it's of type SuitableFood?

```
def blah(t: T)(food: t.SuitableFood) = ...
```

Note that it has to be in a separate parameter list to depend on `t`.

The reason `def blah(t: T, food: T#SuitableFood)` doesn't work is because it would allow below code:

```
val lassie: Animal = new Dog
val cat: Animal = new Cat
val catFood: Animal#SuitableFood = new cat.SuitableFood
blah(lassie, catFood)
```

Comment: Can you explain what is happening here. Or point me to some resources! Thank you very much!